# Using "is to be" instead of "has to be"

Tags: verbs

In a sentence like "The topic has to be interesting for you" "is to be" can be used instead of "has to be"?
Is it correct, is it sometimes used or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**probably not, but it does depend on context**

The phrase "has to be" implies 'compulsion' - i.e. that there is a reason for the topic to be interesting. It also may be used of either the present or the future. For example, said of a topic you are studying:

> I know you chose this topic for your thesis, so this topic has to be interesting for you.

is about the present. But:

> I want you to choose a topic to study next, and this topic has to be interesting for you.

is about the future.

Unlike the two possibilities above "is to be" can only be used about the future. So it is reasonable to substitute "is to be" into the second sentence, but not the first.